# how can I call a function of my plugin from the frontend in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new in WP and reading the tutorials there is no enough info about this (as far as Ive seen, I succesfully created the backend admin and all=, but I have a doubt if is possible to do this.

Is it possible to do a do_action and call a function of my plugin?

I have this so far...

at my plugin file

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'i_am_hook');

    function i_am_hook($a, $b){
        echo "hi";
    }
```

and at my page template I have this...

```
do_action( 'i_am_hook', $a, $b );
```

Is it possible to do something similar? Ive checked other ways to do it, so far, none of them have worked.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why don't you enable an AJAX call, and have it to call your function ?

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: with `front-end` you mean JavaScript ?  Do you know what AJAX is, and how it works?